# Touch event of a picture without using UIButton

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uibutton, ibaction

Is it possible to register a touch of a picture without using UIButton? And if it is, how can i do this?

I can just think of changing the background of a button in the code, and then use IBAction to detect the touch.

Btw, sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. You can put a `UITapGestureRecognizer` on a UIImageView (remember to set the  image view's `userInteractionEnabled` property to YES):

```
// assumes "myImageView" is your UIImageView that has user interaction enabled
UITapGestureRecognizer * tap = [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tap:)] autorelease];
[myImageView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

later in your controller...

```
- (void)tap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer 
{
    // whatever you want
}
```

---

However, you can set up a UIButton to basically be a dumb image. Just set the background image for the normal state, disable all the adjusting on highlighting and touches, and you should have exactly what you're thinking of.

If I've misunderstood what you're getting at, feel free to clarify.

Comment: Ok, i have just heard about UITapGestureRecognizer, and never used it. Could you show me a example how i can use UITapGestureRecognizer at a picture?

Comment: By the way, why do i have to turn userInteractionEnabled to YES?

Comment: @Espen: Because if it's NO, the gesture recognizer never receives the input at all, and image views have it set to NO by default. (P.S. If this answered your question, click the checkmark on the left side. Thanks. :) Welcome to stack overflow.)

Comment: Hehe, oki. Thank you. I tried, but a message appeared: "Vote Up requires 15 reputation
(click on this box to dismiss)"